How can I catch the ServiceBusTrigger message
I need a middleware to catch the ServiceBusTrigger message. My wish is save the ServiceBusMessage on meu log storage.
The Middleware seems the best options to do that, in order to share it with other internal projects
In the past, I could catch from Context.BindingContext.BindingData, but it seems that the value is no longer there
internal class LoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        foreach (var (_, value) in context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings)
        {
            if (value.Type == "serviceBusTrigger")
            {
                var payload = GetPayload(context, value);

                if (payload != null)
                {
                    var loggingStore = context.InstanceServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggingStore>();
                    loggingStore.Save(payload);
                }
            }
        }

        await next(context);
    }

    static string? GetPayload(FunctionContext context, BindingMetadata inputBindingMetadata)
    {
        if (context.BindingContext.BindingData.TryGetValue(inputBindingMetadata.Name, out var value) && value != null)
        {
            var inputValue = value.ToString();
            return inputValue;
        }

        return null;
    }
}



What is your full code and why cant use azure service bus trigger? and why do you need a middleware

Hi, thansk for attention. I rewrote the question to answer your doubts
